# Column count not working as expected on firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, column-count

Actually I'm working on this project:
[Project page](http://discutiamo.org/casale/meeting-2/)

This is Google Chrome:
[image: Google Chrome as I would like it to be in any browser]
This is Firefox buggy version:
[image]

On IE11 and Chrome I can see it almost in the same way, as expected.
The issue is with Firefox.
Column-count doesn't work as in other browsers.
I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Website is Bootstrap based.
Here the code that generates the top part of the page:

```
<div class="lefttext">

    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'expo_page', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="row col-md-12">

            <h2 class="titlecontact text-left"><?php the_title();?></h2>

            <div class="section-divider big col-md-12"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 row">

            <?php the_content();?>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div><!-- .lefttext -->
```

Here is the css:

```
.lefttext{

column-count: 2;

column-gap: 20px;

-moz-column-count: 2;

-moz-column-gap: 20px;

-webkit-column-count: 2;

-webkit-column-gap: 20px;

margin: 20px 0 0 0;
```

}

If needed this is the HTML generated by Wordpress:

```
<div class="lefttext">



            <div class="row col-md-12">

                <h2 class="titlecontact text-left">MEETING &amp; CONFERENZE AL CASALE BORGHESE</h2>

                <div class="section-divider big col-md-12"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 row">

                <p style="text-align: left;">La location di un evento richiede una scelta accurata: i dettagli dell’arredo, l’atmosfera, l’organizzazione degli spazi sono tutti elementi essenziali per conferenze e meeting dall’elevata qualità. <em>Casale Borghese</em> ti propone i suoi lussuosi ambienti d’epoca per un evento di successo.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><em>Casale Borghese</em> suggerisce una formula esclusiva per l’organizzazione efficace e chic di meeting e conferenze:</p>
<p><br></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>AMBIENTE DI LUSSO</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Sia all’interno che all’esterno del palmento, è possibile usufruire di una varietà di spazi funzionali, i quali si estendono fra il lusso e la versatilità dell’antico casale. Il casale dispone di due aree principali:</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">• PALMENTO: comprende un’ampia sala retrò – chic ricavata al suo interno e restaurata in stile contemporaneo. L’interno del Palmento è articolato in più spazi dalla sontuosa architettura ed è ideale per allestire conferenze esclusive e organizzare raffinati meeting.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">• GIARDINO D’EPOCA: consiste in un lussuoso angolo verde altamente versatile, corredato da piscina e gazebo rustico. Ideale per un meeting esclusivo o una conferenza alternativa, il giardino del casale consente inoltre di godere di uno spazio aggiuntivo, brioso e chic, per l’intrattenimento dei partecipanti all’evento.</p>
<hr>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>ALLESTIMENTO SMART</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Dalla disposizione di banchetti e suppellettili alle illuminazioni, la varietà di ambienti del casale ti consente di giocare con gli spazi e scegliere la soluzione più adatta a soddisfare le tue esigenze in fatto di organizzazione e stile.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Per meeting e conferenze esclusive, il casale ti propone una serie di elementi da scegliere per la tua formula personalizzata:</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">• allestimento<br>
• suppellettili<br>
• musica<br>
• illuminazione interna ed esterna<br>
• decorazioni<br>
• addobbi floreali</p>

            </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<div class="lefttext">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
```

Doesn't really make sense. In most cases, `col-*`s should only be children of `row`s, but `col-md-12` is directly under `lefttext` instead. Also, I don't think you're supposed to use `col-*` and `row` on the same element either.

I think you want:

```
<div class="lefttext">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
```

Comment: The silly thing is that actually works on FF and not on Chrome -.-'

Answer (score 1):

Well, your *content* contains a lot of `col-md-*`-class elements.
`bootstrap` has this rule:

```
@media (min-width:992px){
    .col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12{
        float:left
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

The `float: left;` here triggers what appears to be a column break. Not sure if this is a bug in Firefox, or if the other browsers are actually buggy... There should be something in the spec I suppose...

Anyway, removing the `float: left;` fixes the unwanted column breaks.